# How many IP addresses that can be configured for multiple groups of ConfigNode and DataNode in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: ip-address, apache-iotdb, iotdb

In the distributed cluster of Apache IoTDB with 3 ConfigNodes and 3 DataNodes, how many IP addresses should I configure for the ConfigNode configuration parameter `cn_target_config_node_list`, and the DataNodes configuration parameter `dn_target_config_node_list`? When I set the first ConfigNode and DataNode with one local IP, should the later nodes also be set to the address of the first nodes? Or can I configure 3 addresses for these 3 ConfigNodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cn_target_config_node list` in the startup parameters of ConfigNode in Apache IoTDB currently only supports the configuration of one node, so it is recommended to configure it as `Seed-ConfigNode` (the first node to be started).
The `dn_target config_node_list` in the startup parameters of DataNode supports configuring multiple ConfigNodes to improve fault tolerance during restart process. Therefore, it is recommended to configure it as a list of all ConfigNodes.